# HAproxy process has been killed unexpectlly when HAproxy service wss reloaded by sysv init script in CentOS7.2

Tags: haproxy, centos7, systemd

I installed the HAproxy(1.5.14-3.el7) from CentOS7.2 repository.
When I reload HAproxy service with a wrong haproxy.cfg,
the return code of reload is incorrect.

About HAproxy,OS,systemd information pls see below:

```
[root@unknown ~]# rpm -qa | egrep haproxy
haproxy-1.5.14-3.el7.x86_64
[root@unknown ~]#

[root@unknown ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
[root@unknown ~]#

[root@unknown ~]# rpm -qa | egrep systemd
systemd-libs-219-19.el7.x86_64
systemd-219-19.el7.x86_64
systemd-sysv-219-19.el7.x86_64
[root@unknown ~]#
```

The return code of reload is incorrect.

```
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  haproxy.service
●haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; disabled;     vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-07 11:24:41 UTC; 4s ago
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# more /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
XXXX                                                 **--> I added an incorrect keyword into haproxy.cfg**
Global
....
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy reload
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl reload  haproxy.service
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# echo $?
0                                                   **--> It was sucessful !!!**

[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  haproxy.service
● haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-07 11:24:41 UTC; 21s ago
  Process: 16507 ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 16464 (haproxy-systemd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/haproxy.service
           tq16464 /usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid
           tq16465 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
           mq16466 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds

Jun 07 11:24:41 unknown systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jun 07 11:24:41 unknown systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Jun 07 11:24:41 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy...id -Ds
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown systemd[1]: Reloaded HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: re-executing
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy... 16466
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: [ALERT] 158/112457 (16508) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:9]: unknown k...ction.  **--> In fact, it was wrong**
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: [ALERT] 158/112457 (16508) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/hap...xy.cfg
Jun 07 11:24:57 unknown haproxy-systemd-wrapper[16464]: [ALERT] 158/112457 (16508) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

So I descided to use the sysv init.d script to start/reload/stop HAproxy service.

sysv init.d script:

```
[root@unknown ~]# cat /etc/init.d/haproxy
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: HA-Proxy is a TCP/HTTP reverse proxy which is particularly suited \
#              for high availability environments.
# processname: haproxy
# config: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
# pidfile: /var/run/haproxy.pid

# Script Author: Simon Matter <simon.matter@invoca.ch>
# Version: 2004060600

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: HA-Proxy
# Required-Start: $network $syslog sshd
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: HAProxy
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.
if [ -f /etc/init.d/functions ]; then
  . /etc/init.d/functions
elif [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ] ; then
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
else
  exit 0
fi

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
#[ ${NETWORKING} = "no" ] && exit 0

# This is our service name
BASENAME=`basename $0`
if [ -L $0 ]; then
  BASENAME=`find $0 -name $BASENAME -printf %l`
  BASENAME=`basename $BASENAME`
fi

[ -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg ] || exit 1

RETVAL=0

start() {
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -c -q -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Errors found in configuration file, check it with '$BASENAME check'."
    return 1
  fi

  echo -n "Starting $BASENAME: "
  daemon /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -D -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg -p /var/run/$BASENAME.pid
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$BASENAME
  return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
  killproc $BASENAME -USR1
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$BASENAME
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/run/$BASENAME.pid
  return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -c -q -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Errors found in configuration file, check it with '$BASENAME check'."
    return 1
  fi
  stop
  start
}

reload() {
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -c -q -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Errors found in configuration file, check it with '$BASENAME check'."
    return 1
  fi
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -D -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg -p /var/run/$BASENAME.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/$BASENAME.pid)
}

check() {
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -c -q -V -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
}

rhstatus() {
  status $BASENAME
}

    condrestart() {
  [ -e /var/lock/subsys/$BASENAME ] && restart || :
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    restart
    ;;
  reload)
    reload
    ;;
  condrestart)
    condrestart
    ;;
  status)
    rhstatus
    ;;
  check)
    check
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $BASENAME {start|stop|restart|reload|condrestart|status|check}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

When I reloaded HAproxy serivce with the correct haproxy.cfg, 
the command(service haproxy reload) returned 0,
but HAproxy's status became failed.

```
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy status
● haproxy.service - LSB: HAProxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-07 11:33:22 UTC; 1h 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16636 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16641 (haproxy)
   CGroup: /system.slice/haproxy.service
           mq16641 /usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid

Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HAProxy...
Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown haproxy[16636]: Starting haproxy: [  OK  ]
Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown systemd[1]: Started LSB: HAProxy.
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy reload
Reloading haproxy configuration (via systemctl):           [  OK  ]
[root@unknown ~]# echo $?
0                                                      **--> It was sucessful !!!**
[root@unknown ~]#
[root@unknown ~]# service haproxy status
● haproxy.service - LSB: HAProxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2016-06-07 12:48:01 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16869 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16863 ExecReload=/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16636 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16868 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HAProxy...
Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown haproxy[16636]: Starting haproxy: [  OK  ]
Jun 07 11:33:22 unknown systemd[1]: Started LSB: HAProxy.
Jun 07 12:48:00 unknown systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: HAProxy.
Jun 07 12:48:00 unknown systemd[1]: haproxy.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL **--> It was killed ,but I don't know which process killed it, Cgroup ?**
Jun 07 12:48:01 unknown haproxy[16869]: [FAILED]
Jun 07 12:48:01 unknown systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
Jun 07 12:48:01 unknown systemd[1]: haproxy.service failed.
[root@unknown ~]#
```

I used a newer systemd to get the detailed logs

```
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HAProxy...
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[7010]: Executing: /etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy start
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb haproxy[7010]: Starting haproxy: [  OK  ]
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: Child 7010 belongs to haproxy.service
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service got final SIGCHLD for state start
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: Main PID loaded: 7015
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service changed start -> running
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: Job haproxy.service/start finished, result=done
Jun 07 13:02:59 elb systemd[1]: Started LSB: HAProxy.          **--> start HAproxy successfully **


Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job haproxy.service/reload/replace
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Installed new job haproxy.service/reload as 9504
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Enqueued job haproxy.service/reload as 9504


Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: About to execute: /etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy reload
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Forked /etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy as 7060
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service changed running -> reload
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[7060]: Executing: /etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy reload
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Child 7015 belongs to haproxy.service
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Main PID changing: 7015 -> 7065
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Child 7060 belongs to haproxy.service
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service got final SIGCHLD for state reload
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service changed reload -> running
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Job haproxy.service/reload finished, result=done
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: HAProxy.   **--> successful to reload HAproxy**

Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Child 7065 belongs to haproxy.service
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL **--> process 7065 has been killed unexpectly**
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service changed running -> failed
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service failed.
Jun 07 13:03:27 elb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: cgroup is empty **-->Did cgroup killed process 7065? Is it a bug of systemd? **
```

In CentOS7.1, I use the sysv init script (pls see above) to reload haproxy ,and  'service haproxy reload' command could return correct result.

I don't know what is wrong in CentOS7.2. I just want to get following results of reloading HAproxy.

- When haproxy.cfg file is incorrect, 'service haproxy reload' command returns 1
- When haproxy.cfg file is correct, 'service haproxy reload' command returns 0

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would guess this is a SELinux issue. you can try change for below:
:
vi /etc/selinux/config

## SELINUX=enforcing

## SELINUXTYPE=targeted

SELINUX=disabled

:wq!  #save and quit

Comment: Disabling SELinux is a sledgehammer. It's better to get to the root of the issue, rather than just effectively turning off security.